# How to make the main ticks of \psgraph get aligned with the main grids of \psgrid?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

How to make the main ticks of `\psgraph` get aligned with the main grids of `\psgrid`?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0bp,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\TrigLabelBase{4}
\FPeval\XMin{0-pi}
\FPeval\XMax{2*pi}
\FPset\YMin{-3}
\FPset\YMax{3}

\FPeval\DeltaX{pi/TrigLabelBase}
\FPeval\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\Left{XMin-DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Right{XMax+DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Bottom{YMin-DeltaY/4}
\FPeval\Top{YMax+DeltaY/4}

\newlength\Width\Width=12cm
\newlength\Height\Height=6cm

\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt
\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridwidth=0.4pt,% 0.8pt
    gridcolor=red!20,% black
    griddots=0,% 0 
    %=====================================
    gridlabels=0pt,% 10pt
    gridfont=NimbusSanL-Regu,
    gridlabelcolor=blue!50,% black, must not use dvipsnames
    %=====================================
    subgriddiv=10,% 5
    subgridwidth=0.1pt,% 0.4pt
    subgridcolor=green!50,% gray
    subgriddots=0% 0
}

\psset
{
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    trigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    tickcolor=gray,
    ticksize=0 -4pt,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    style=gridstyle,
}




\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}[dx=\DeltaX,dy=\DeltaY,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}%{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psgrid[xunit=\DeltaX,dx=\DeltaX](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide *minimal* examples and not such bombastic ones ...

```
\psgrid[xunit=\DeltaX](-4,-3)(8,3)% 4 ticks left, 8 ticks right
```

An alternative:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0bp,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{urx=1cm,ury=1cm,llx=-1cm,lly=-1cm,
       trigLabels,trigLabelBase=4,
       xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$,tickcolor=gray,
       labelFontSize=\scriptstyle}
\pstFPdiv\DeltaX{\psPi}{4}
\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}[dx=\DeltaX,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-3.1415,-3)(6.283,3){12cm}{!}
  \psaxes[linecolor=gray,dx=\DeltaX,labels=none,subticks=10,subtickwidth=0.1pt,
    subtickcolor=green!50,tickcolor=red!50,
    xticksize=-3 3,yticksize=-\psPi\space \psPiTwo,subticksize=1](0,0)(-\psPi,-3)(\psPiTwo,3)
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

`\psgrid` always uses natural numbers for the x|y area.

[image]

Comment: By the way, natural numbers are only positive integers.

Comment: I meant "uses internally" ...

Comment: How can we get exactly the same output as [mine (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191810/19356) with `psgrid` and `gridpara` keys defined in the latest `pst-plot`? I think it is not possible, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Just for sharing my template based on Herbert's solution plus my own bombastic yet easy-to-use settings.

### Notes about the settings

[image]

### The template

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0-pi}
\FPeval\XMax{2*pi}
\FPeval\YMin{0-pi}
\FPeval\YMax{3*pi/2}

\FPeval\XOL{0-1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0-1/3} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/3} % of DeltaY

\FPset\TrigLabelBase{2}
\FPeval\DeltaX{pi/TrigLabelBase}
\FPeval\DeltaY{pi/TrigLabelBase}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+DeltaX*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+DeltaX*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+DeltaY*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+DeltaY*YOT}

\newlength\Width\Width=12cm
\newlength\Height\Height=8cm

\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    xtrigLabels,
    ytrigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        linecolor=gray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
        axespos=top,
    ]{<->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}%{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psaxes
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickwidth=.4pt,
        subtickwidth=.2pt,
        tickcolor=Red!30,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen!30,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
    ](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This layout is a mandatory requirement rather than a trivial, bombastic setting.